# What is causing SSL-"shutdown while in init" error on dovecot?

Tags: dovecot, openssl

At one of my systems I can see from time to time error messages like:

```
TLS: SSL_read() failed: error:140E0197:SSL routines:SSL_shutdown:shutdown while in init
```

What might causes these errors?

Answer (score 1):

This error means dovecot called SSL_shutdown() before full SSL handshake with client was made.

It was fixed (by not calling SSL_shutdown() in such case) in dovecot 2.3.2 with [this commit](https://github.com/dovecot/core/commit/5231b55f35f862976508358716c7c304d306b0d6):

```
commit 5231b55f35f862976508358716c7c304d306b0d6
Author: Kadlecsik József
Date:   Tue Mar 20 12:21:33 2018 +0200

    lib-ssl-iostream: Fix openssl compatibility issue introduced in OpenSSL 1.0.2f

    Fixes dovecot: imap-login: Debug: SSL error: SSL_read() failed: error:140E0197:SSL routines:SSL_shutdown:shutdown while in init
```